# Can I access and alter a variable from within a function or procedure?

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-function

I want to create a simple procedure like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE testprozedur (pCondition In Number) IS
BEGIN
  If (pCondition != 0) Then test_counter := test_counter + 1;
      End If;
END testprozedur;
```

and access this procedure from within a pl/sql statement. This statement could look like the following:

```
declare

my_var1 number;
my_var2 number;

begin         

select count(*) into my_var1 from table_1;
select count(*) into my_var2 from table_2;

exec testprozedur(my_var1 - my_var2);
end;
```

I tried creating a package for the variable "test_counter" but it didn't work. Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Why do you think you need the `test_counter` variable? Is it meant to increase within a session or across all sessions?

Comment: The SQL developer says that "test_counter" can't be on the left side of en equal sign. The variable is meant to increase until i define it to be zero again.

Comment: Works fine for me? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09c601eb3e9b4ed288c80350c3916c33

Comment: @Boneist you're right. Maybe it was because I didn't define test_counter to be zero in the Package. Anyway, thank you!